# I want to submit multiple forms with one submit button. PHP

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I construct the view for every question in a database. The view shows the questions and the options for every question in the database.

I want the student can submit all the questions with one button. 
I want to get the submitted answers of every question in an array so I can check if answer is right.

I tried to place all the answers in one form. I got all the answers as one array.

**THE VIEW**

```
$opcionesC = "<div class='OpcionesC'>
                <h3>$preguntaAUX</h3>";
$opcionesC .= "<form method='post' action='preguntaC.php'>";

foreach ($opciones as $fila){
    $opcion=$fila['opcion'];
    $opcionesC.= "<input type='checkbox' name='respuestasAlumno[]' value='$opcion'> $opcion <br>";
}

$opcionesC.="   </form>";
$opcionesC.="</div>";

$vista = "  <form method='post' action='calificar.php'>    
                <input type='submit' value='enviar' name='calificar'>
            </form>";
```

The controller must take the submitted answers  for every question in a different array.
Help me getting the answers for every question in a different array? Should I use a different way to construct the view?

Thanks.

Comment: you can't. a submit button will only submit the form it's part of. if you want other forms elsewhere on the page to be submitted as well, then you'll need to use javascript to pull values out of those other forms and embed them into the form-that-submit-was-clicked-in.

Comment: Why don't you just put it all into one big form?

Comment: @MattyF The accepted answer on that question is wrong. And wow is it wrong!

Comment: If you make the one button send two Ajax requests with the data from the respective forms, you can submit both forms via one button.